# Proper way to add text on top of navbar bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I tried to add this code after a ul tag:

```
<p class="navbar-text pull-right">
    <strong>Toll Free Num: 1 300 22 6868</strong>
</p>
```

but I got these results

[bootstrap navbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTWIu.png)

What is the proper way to add the text below or on top of contact?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlfow. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="tollfree">toll free</div>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css

```
ul.navbar-nav li
        {
        position:relative;
        }
        .tollfree
        {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
        }
```

style the navigation bar links accordingly
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the **div** tag before or after **nav** tag

See below.

```
 <div class="text-right"><strong>Toll Free Num: 1 300 22 6868</strong></div>
```